# LM317 with potentiometer

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[image]

According to above equation doesn't output voltage depend on input voltage?

I have made this regulator circuit but it can't increase output voltage than the input voltage.

So can't we increase voltage above 12V if we input 12V?

[image]

Comment: There is no input voltage in this equation.

Comment: An LM317 is not a boost regulator. It's a 'simple' linear regulator, and it has a 'drop-out' voltage. Read the rest of the datasheet which you got that formula from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, since the input voltage doesn't even appear in the equation. And the "can it raise the voltage?" question makes no sense, given that Chanuka has access to the datasheet.

Comment: I would guess that the OP confused the units \$V\$ with \$V_{in}\$.

Comment: The V in the equation does make it a little confusing.  Surely the V is not necessary.

Comment: Let we assume the input voltage is 12V. R2=10K,R1=1K.(actually these are the values i applied.)so when when i applied above values V_out is equal to 13.75V.But i get only 12V to 0V regulation

Comment: Mathematically, Vout will be 13.75V. But the LM317 cannot have a Vout higher than Vin. It is a linear regulator, **NOT** a boost regulator. The maximum it can output is Vin - Vdropout. If you are supplying it with 12V only, you won't get any more than 10-11V out (dependent on load current)

Comment: MCG thanks mate for the answer.what is Vdropout.

Comment: I think you may need to re-word your question. I think I get what you are saying now, but it's a bit difficult, and I am assuming English sin't your first language. Vdropout is basically the headroom you need for a stable output. If you have  a dropout voltage of 1V, then you will need at least 13V to get 12V out. The LM317 has a dropout voltage that changes with load current, as you can see in the graph on page 6 of National Semiconductors version of the datasheet: https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/898800.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The equation is correct — the output voltage is indeed independent of the input voltage — but the equation only applies when the rest of the operating requirements of the device are met, specified elsewhere in the datasheet. Among these are the requirement that V_in > V_out + V_dropout. If this requirement is not met, then the first equation no longer applies.